# How can I find the equation generated using the **K-Star** algorithm in Weka?

Tags: excel, algorithm, weka, prediction

I have CSV file which contains some variables about traffic engineering (such as Number of lanes, quality of lane, population, etc...).

The last column is ADT(average daily traffic) which is calculated based on sensors located on the roads.

I want to predict the ADT for other roads with the same variables and finally compare my predicted ADT with actual ones in my CSV file.

I divided my data set into two parts( 70% and 30%).

In Weka, using **K-Star** algorithm I take 70% of my data set choosing the option `use training set` and test the other 30% choosing `supplied test set`.

I get a good result with almost 3% error to predict the ADT. But the problem is that it does not provide any equation to show me how it calculated the ADT, making it impossible to apply the equation for other data sets.

Nevertheless when I use **Linear regression** algorithm (instead of K-Star), the result is not good (65% of error) but it provides an equation to calculate the ADT.

How can I find the equation generated using the **K-Star** algorithm ?

Comment: Welcome to SO Mohammad ! Please read the guide on how to ask "good" questions. It helps everyone getting fast and relevant answers as well as other users finding question/answer peers easily.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

K-star algorithm is a lazy classifier which finds "similar members" to the instance your are trying to classify and uses their labels to provide classification (sort of K-nearest-neighbors). The only equation the algorithm uses is the similarity function between two instances (e.g. Euclidean distance).

If you want to use the classifier you can output the model to a file and then use Weka (via code, GUI and maybe command line) to classify other data sets.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. But still I cannot extract any equation. any other idea?

Comment: Read my answer again. The algorithm does not output an equation.